# error "app not installed" when installing apk

Tags: android

I have an app in development that I am trying to copy to a tablet to test. 
The app will run in the emulator and will run on the tablet when connected by USB.  This is my first Android app so forgive me for the newbie question.

My USB cable is temperamental and until I get a new one I am copying the apk to the tablet via dropbox.  I also tried emailing myself the apk.  All result in the same issue.

When I try to install the app I get the error "app not installed".  But I have uninstalled previous versions and made sure it does not show in the app drawer.  I even looked through the app drawer and made sure there were no unrecognized apps.

If I change the build type to debug and generate an app-debug.apk that will install and run fine on the tablet.

But If I change the build type to release and try to install the app-release.apk I get that error.

I have also tried this on another tablet and my phone to see what happens and have exactly the same issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you followed the steps to sign your app? Release is a bit different than debug in this sense. https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Comment: May be you need to accept the install from adb pop-up while installing from the Android studio? Have u did that, you get a pop-up during installation of the app on the device

Comment: What sdk is your tablet running on? 6, 5, 4, etc.?

Comment: I have not signed the app.  I looked at the link you provided and it is very confusing, keys, passwords oh my.

Can you please help clarify the app signing process?

Comment: I do not know what version SDK my tablet is running.  If you tell me where to find that info I will post it

Answer (score 0):

Still can not get this to work.  I have tried to generate a keystore then build signed app.

If I try to run this app-release.apk on any device I get the "app not installed error".